# ng-repeat Efficiency and Working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using **ng-repeat** for my **Model** render in **angular** ,
if i Push new Element in Model/Collection , Will angular only deal with Update or Loop through the whole model again.??

Comment: Here this link might help you [Model Best Practices](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: @Adnan take a look at my answer

Comment: I know that newly added is Pushed/Render.But the Question is that on New item Push in Collection,Does All Collection get traversed  or Angular only pick the item from Collection that is new Added and Render it.

Answer (score 1):

My experience (using Angular version 1.2.7) is such that whenever something changed in collection, the whole ng-repeat was repainted. 
You can easily test it by modifying the generated DOM. For example by adding custom attributes like my-id="1", my-id="2" etc to the DOM elements.
Then change something in your collection, which will trigger new $digest cycle.
Angular will pick up the change and redraw the DOM -> your custom attributes will disappear.

So I would argue that Angular loops through the whole model.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation it is clearly mentioned:

[ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

> ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope

Angular associates an identity to every item, the elements already associated to the existing items of the collection won't be recreated.

Hence, only elements that are removed from the collection, are removed from the DOM. Furthermore, if an item moves within the collection it doesn’t need a new scope, but it needs to be moved in the DOM.